# Jet stream of water

Tags: materials, particles, fluid-simulation

I would like to simulate a stream of water like the one in the picture, but I don't know how to simulate the fast-moving, white water.
Should I use particles to simulate foam or is it much better to concentrate in the material properties?
Thanks

[image: Jet stream of water with a flyboard]

Comment: I've tried 'Fluid' but it's totatlly not what you are looking for, then I've tried 'Particle System > Fluid' with a higher 'Timestamp' it was pretty ok until I increase amount of particles a lot and it's just went nuts. So my last try was with 'Smoke' and this was pretty (-10 temp in smoke flow) good but I cannot reproduce small flow radius at the top and wider at the bottom.

Comment: This guy does it pretty well but he not explain it too much: https://vimeo.com/70788800

Answer (score 9):

### Result:

[image: Result]

This is closest I can get with my PC.

### Setup:

1. Turn on *Metric* units.
2. Create small *Cylinder*. 17x20x60cm with 6 sides.
3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and find *Quick Smoke*.
4. Resize domain to about 5x5x5m - big size prevent from gathering smoke around stream.
5. Place everything like in the picture below.
6. In *Render Tab > Light Paths* make sure *Volume* is greater then 0. Higher value will give smoother stream as light will bounce more in it.

[image: Setup]

### Smoke Flow:

With *Cylinder* selected go to *Physics Tab*.

Change *Temp. Diff.* to *-5*. Lower value gives more speed.

Change *Flow Source > Surface* to *0.1*.

[image: Smoke Flow]

### Smoke Domain:

Change everything as in a picture.

You can increase resolution for more detailed stream.

*Vorticity* change turbulance in stream. In this case it's low because simulation is small in metrics.

*Noise Method > Strenght* control how wide stream will be at the bottom (higher value, wider stream).

[image: Smoke Domain]

### Material:

Materials aren't my thingy so here is only a small modification to smoke base material. Play with *Brightness/Contrast* for stream color.

[image: Materials]

### Blend file:

[image]

### Final toughts:

I think that with higher resolution and better material you could achieve pretty realistic results and my answer will be good starter. In addition to this you can use *particle > fluid* for those little drops around stream.