# Cycles: create water using smoke / volume

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I am trying to simulate a waterfall using this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTMr7ls7J1Y

I got a scene with smoke that acts sufficiently accurate as water pouring down. I am able to render the smoke in cycles. So far, so good. (It is just a test project)

**My problem is: What can I do to make the smoke actually look like water?**

[image]

[image: Smoke material]

Is it possible to assign a material to the smoke volume? So can you work with the smoke volume and create a material with exactly the same shape?

When I tried to use a glass or glossy shader node, the only result I got was the whole smoke domain box rendered with this material.

What can I do? Maybe, there is another, more simple way to create a waterfall?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Using fluid, I don´t get a result near my expectations, partly because of the limited domain size (10 meters):

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you can only assign volume shaders to smoke simulations

Comment: One thing if you don't mind you can simulate actual fluid in physics tab instead for going smoke simulation!

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/jet-stream-of-water/61551#61551 you can tweak it to look like actual waterfall. I've nothing against Steve Lund method but for me it's to slow and to... smokey. Look over here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo3OM5sPUPM

Comment: The only reason I don´t use fluid simulation is the limitated size of the domain. Waterfalls created with fluid always look like tiny caricatures. I don´t know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your method LukeD doesn´t work well, so I think I cannot use it

Comment: What's not working well? For me after couple tweaks results are acceptable.

Comment: @LukeD I added a Bright/Contrast node and fiddled around with the values, but I didn´t get a much brighter smoke. Anyway, what I am seeking is transparent and reflecting water. Using your method, I cannot get such a result. So I think I have to figure out how to work with the fluid sim

Comment: Sadly I cannot help you in detail as my PC isn't powerful enough to handle such big simulation (crash after crash) but Smoke sim is certainly what you want to use. Check again YT link I've provided. You cannot see any reflections in high velocity stream.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your solution another time @LukeD and it worked. I am sorry, I must have got it wrong the first time.

I think you can get acceptable results with this solution:

[image]

Now, the quality depends on the density of the smoke (and, of course, the smoke resolution)
[image]

Material for the smoke domain:
[image: foam material for the smoke domain]

However, if you what to create a slow waterfall, like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTjtHFeZ1zM
with clear water, there must be another method.

I fiddled around with the fluid sim and noticed, that the volume of the inflow object is crucial. I increased it´s size, compared to the example above. There must be enough water flowing into the scene! Thus, fluid sim could do it as well:

[image]

Render time for fluids is way shorter than for smoke, if you have a good grafics card, btw, because smoke doesn´t support GPU computing yet.