# Smoke jet simulation?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I would like to animate a jet of smoke as in [this video clip](https://youtu.be/c4tPQYNpW9k?t=100) (from the movie Interstellar). Here's a short preview:

[image]

Note the important elements are:

1. The smoke is translucent
2. The smoke is very fast at the exhaust
3. The smoke is turbulent and its "radius" increases away from the source, becoming more turbulent
4. The smoke has quite a well defined "contour" - it is not washed out, but ends abruptly in sort of sharp turbulent blades towards the end

I would also like to be able to toggle the jet on and off via a parameter that can be keyframed, simulating the jet firing/shutting off.

So far, I can get a washed out (4 not satisfied) and fairly uniform (3 not satisfied) jet of smoke using pretty much the default Quick Smoke properties together with a particle system flow source. However, I am unable to get the rich turbulent texture of the smoke in the above video. I also do not know how to turn the smoke on/off efficiently such that when it is "off", render time is fast (I don't want to just set the material to nothing, because the physics simulation will then still take up a lot of time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jet stream of water](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/jet-stream-of-water) Only difference here would be density controlled by material. The best way now is to make it with Principled Volume.